# Retrieving custom Object from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I have a dictionary of values

```
class Objects {
    let values = [
    "AAA": ["AAAAAAA", "111111111"],
    "BBB": ["BBBBBBBB", "2222222"],
    "CCC": ["CCCCCCCC", "3333333333"],
    "DDD": ["DDDDDD", "44444444"],
    ]
}
```

Which I turn into custom objects and display in a tableview.

```
struct  Object {
   var heading : String!
   var imageName: String!
}
```

Then the user can select two objects to store in `UserDefaults`

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

func addObject(_ object1: String, object2: String) {

    // Get objects for user
    var userObjects = fetchObjectsFromUserDefaults()

    // Add to user currencies
    userObjects.append([object1,object2])

    //Update user defaults value for key
    // [ [Object1, Object2], [Object1, Object2] ]

    defaults.set(userObject, forKey: "userCurrencies")
}

// Gets [[String]] values from user defaults for key
func fetchObjectsFromUserDefaults() -> [[String]] {
    if let objects = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userObjects") {
        return objects as! [[String]]
    } else {
        return []
    }
}


// Uses [[String]] values and turns them into objects by using the dictionary to determine property values 

func getObject() -> [[Object]] {
    let userObject = fetchObjectsFromUserDefaults()
    // [ [Object1, Object2], [Object1, Object2] ]

    let object = Object()

    var fetchedObject = [[Object]]()

    if !userObjects.isEmpty {
        for c in userObjects {
            var set = [Object]()
            if let val = object.available[c[0]] {
                set.append(Currency(currencyTitle: c[0], imageName: val[0] ))
            }

            if let val2 = object.available[c[1]] {
                set.append(Currency(currencyTitle: c[0], imageName: val2[0] ))
            }

            if !set.isEmpty {
                fetchedObjects.append(set)
            }
        }
        return fetchedObjects
    }

    return [[]]

}
```

**View Controller**

Here I get the objects to load into the `TableView`

```
let fetched = dataManager.getObjects
print(fetched)
self.objects = fetched()
```

However this prints out

> (Function)

What am I doing wrong and is their a better method of storing and retrieving this data from user defaults ? I feel this is over kill and there is a swifter and safer approach.

Comment: You only call the function once. It looks like you probably at least want to call it in the `print` statement (`print(fetched())` to print the results. Or is the print statement even the problem you're trying to address?

Comment: You need to make your custom object conform to NSCoding and you will need to encode/decode it and persist it as Data to UserDefaults. Btw don't use value(forKey:) method it is only meant to be used with KVO and if you are using Swift 4 or later it is preferable to use Codable protocol to encode/decode your custom objects.

Comment: Another thing to mention is that structures can't conform to NSCoding (you need to subclass NSObject). Make it conform to Codable protocol and save th encoded data to a plist file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1.

Make your struct `Codable`.  The compiler will write all of the functions for you if all of the members of your `struct` are `Codable` and fortunately `String` is `Codable` so its just:

```
struct Object: Codable {
  var heading : String!
  var imageName: String!
}
```

Step 2.

The problem with `Codable` is that it converts to and from `Data`, but you want to convert to and from a `Dictionary`.  Fortunately JSONSerialization converts from `Data` to `Dictionary` so make a new protocol and give it a default implementation with a protocol extension:

```
protocol JSONRepresentable {
  init?(json: [String: Any])
  func json() -> [String: Any]
}
extension JSONRepresentable where Self: Codable {
  init?(json: [String:Any]) {
    guard let value = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: []))
      .flatMap ({ try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: $0) }) else {
        return nil
    }
    self = value
  }
  func json() -> [String:Any] {
    return (try? JSONEncoder().encode(self))
      .flatMap { try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: $0, options: []) } as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
  }
}
```

Step 3.

Conform your struct to `JSONRepresentable`

```
struct Object: Codable, JSONRepresentable {
  var heading : String!
  var imageName: String!
}
```

Step 4.

Place your object into Userdefaults and get it out again:

```
let o = Object.init(heading: "s", imageName: "a").json()
UserDefaults.standard.set(o, forKey: "test")
print(Object.init(json: UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "test") ?? [:]))
```

Here is the whole playground if you want to try:

```
import UIKit

struct Object: Codable, JSONRepresentable {
  var heading : String!
  var imageName: String!
}

protocol JSONRepresentable {
  init?(json: [String: Any])
  func json() -> [String: Any]
}
extension JSONRepresentable where Self: Codable {
  init?(json: [String:Any]) {
    guard let value = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: []))
      .flatMap ({ try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: $0) }) else {
        return nil
    }
    self = value
  }
  func json() -> [String:Any] {
    return (try? JSONEncoder().encode(self))
      .flatMap { try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: $0, options: []) } as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
  }
}

let o = Object.init(heading: "s", imageName: "a").json()
UserDefaults.standard.set(o, forKey: "test")
print(Object.init(json: UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "test") ?? [:]))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great help, just trying to completely get it to work for my project, for example when adding the objects I get the following in the print statement `Optional(TestApp.Currency(heading: nil, imageName: nil))`

Comment: Also I need to add a pair of Objects so when saving and retrieving them the format of the objects are an array within an array with two objects (I compare each object in each table view cell)  [ [Object, Object] ]

Comment: Just figuring these final parts out and doing some further reading, but this is more of what I was looking for

Comment: Array<SomeCodable> is also Codable.  so it works the same way.